# Looking to increase the efficiency of this inline assembly, can someone offer advice?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, inline-assembly

Thank you everyone for being patient with me. I just had to wrap my head around what I was looking at. Apologies for the slowness, just trying to learn and understand.

After re-reading everyone's comments and looking over the code a few times, I realize that my question was aimed in the wrong direction. I

Would I replace the the two lines with simple assembly instructions? Or would I have to do something like `asm()`. I guess this is where I'm confused. Once I know this, I think I take it from there.

**EDIT** 

I didn't realize I omitted this from the post. Obviously the most important part, thank you Oli for pointing it out.

*The goal is to replace the two lines of code inside the for loop in the attached program with inline assembly code.  You must get the same output from your inline assembly code. (perform the same results, with the same number of loops)*

**C :**

```
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "time.h"

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int num1 = 10;
    int num2 = 27;
    int sum = 0;
    int cases = 0;
    int loose = 0;
    float time1 = 0;
    float time2 = 0;
    float time = 0;
    int i = 0;

    sum = num1 + num2;

    asm("xor %%eax,%%eax;"
        "mov %1,%%eax;"
        "add %2,%%eax;"
        "mov %%eax,%0;"
        :"=r"(sum)                   /* outputs */
        :"r"(num1),"r"(num2)         /* input   */
        :"%eax");                    /*clobber list*/

    printf("The sum is %d \n",sum);

    time1 = clock();
    for (i = 0; i<1000000000; i++)
    { 

        cases = i/num1;
        loose = i%num1;

    }  
    printf("The number of cases are %d \n",cases);
    printf("The number of loose items are %d \n",loose);

    time2 = clock();

    time = (time2 - time1) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    printf("The elapsed time is %f seconds \n", time);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

**Assembly :**

```
.file   "inlineAsm.c"
.def    ___main;    .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
.section .rdata,"dr"

LC1:
    .ascii "The sum is %d \12\0"
LC2:
    .ascii "The number of cases are %d \12\0"
    .align 4
LC3:
    .ascii "The number of loose items are %d \12\0"
    .align 4
LC5:
    .ascii "The elapsed time is %f seconds \12\0"
LC6:
    .ascii "pause\0"
    .align 4
LC4:
    .long   1148846080
    .text
.globl _main
    .def    _main;  .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef

_main:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    subl    $56, %esp
    andl    $-16, %esp
    movl    $0, %eax
    addl    $15, %eax
    addl    $15, %eax
    shrl    $4, %eax
    sall    $4, %eax
    movl    %eax, -40(%ebp)
    movl    -40(%ebp), %eax
    call    __alloca
    call    ___main
    movl    $10, -4(%ebp)
    movl    $27, -8(%ebp)
    movl    $0, -12(%ebp)
    movl    $0, -16(%ebp)
    movl    $0, -20(%ebp)
    movl    $0x00000000, %eax
    movl    %eax, -24(%ebp)
    movl    $0x00000000, %eax
    movl    %eax, -28(%ebp)
    movl    $0x00000000, %eax
    movl    %eax, -32(%ebp)
    movl    $0, -36(%ebp)
    movl    -8(%ebp), %eax
    addl    -4(%ebp), %eax
    movl    %eax, -12(%ebp)
    movl    -4(%ebp), %ecx
    movl    -8(%ebp), %edx
/APP
    xor %eax,%eax;mov %ecx,%eax;add %edx,%eax;mov %eax,%edx;
/NO_APP
    movl    %edx, %eax
    movl    %eax, -12(%ebp)
    movl    -12(%ebp), %eax
    movl    %eax, 4(%esp)
    movl    $LC1, (%esp)
    call    _printf
    call    _clock
    pushl   %eax
    fildl   (%esp)
    leal    4(%esp), %esp
    fstps   -24(%ebp)
    movl    $0, -36(%ebp)
L2:
    cmpl    $999999999, -36(%ebp)
    jg  L3
    movl    -36(%ebp), %edx
    leal    -4(%ebp), %ecx
    movl    %ecx, -40(%ebp)
    movl    %edx, %eax
    movl    -40(%ebp), %ecx
    cltd
    idivl   (%ecx)
    movl    %eax, -40(%ebp)
    movl    -40(%ebp), %eax
    movl    %eax, -16(%ebp)
    movl    -36(%ebp), %edx
    leal    -4(%ebp), %ecx
    movl    %ecx, -40(%ebp)
    movl    %edx, %eax
    movl    -40(%ebp), %ecx
    cltd
    idivl   (%ecx)
    movl    %edx, -20(%ebp)
    leal    -36(%ebp), %eax
    incl    (%eax)
    jmp L2
L3:
    movl    -16(%ebp), %eax
    movl    %eax, 4(%esp)
    movl    $LC2, (%esp)
    call    _printf
    movl    -20(%ebp), %eax
    movl    %eax, 4(%esp)
    movl    $LC3, (%esp)
    call    _printf
    call    _clock
    pushl   %eax
    fildl   (%esp)
    leal    4(%esp), %esp
    fstps   -28(%ebp)
    flds    -28(%ebp)
    fsubs   -24(%ebp)
    flds    LC4
    fdivrp  %st, %st(1)
    fstps   -32(%ebp)
    flds    -32(%ebp)
    fstpl   4(%esp)
    movl    $LC5, (%esp)
    call    _printf
    movl    $LC6, (%esp)
    call    _system
    movl    $0, %eax
    leave
    ret
    .def    _system     ;.scl   3;  .type   32; .endef
    .def    _clock      ;.scl   3;  .type   32; .endef
    .def    _printf     ;.scl   3;  .type   32; .endef
```

**Output :**

```
/*
The sum is 37
The number of cases are 99999999
The number of loose items are 9
The elapsed time is 9.359000 seconds
Press any key to continue . . .
*/
```

Comment: This is probably a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: What is the purpose of this code?  Why is there inline assembler **outside** the loop that (apparently) iterates 1000000000 times?

Comment: @BrianRoach Thank you for the link, I'll check it out and post it over there. I'll leave it here as well just in case someone is interested in explaining what is going on, as I don't fully understand it

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I'm new to using inline asm and this is a program that I'm supposed to improve. I'm still trying to fully understand what all of it is doing.

Comment: I tried to write inline assembly once to make my quicksort faster... the C compiler was *much* smarter than I.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the info you added in the recent edit, you need to modify the code inside the loop to make the program faster.

It looks to me like the reason the program is slow is because it's looping 1000000000 times for no reason.

Obviously, the best thing to do would be to eliminate the loop altogether.  However, if you're restricted to modifying only the code inside the loop, could you perhaps make the loop do NOOP on every iteration except the final one?

Note: This is a strange enough question that I still think there may be some misunderstanding about the parameters of the assignment.

Edit: Let's look at the inline assembly:

```
asm("xor %%eax,%%eax;"
    "mov %1,%%eax;"
    "add %2,%%eax;"
    "mov %%eax,%0;"
    :"=r"(sum)                   /* outputs */
    :"r"(num1),"r"(num2)         /* input   */
    :"%eax");                    /*clobber list*/
```

For the purposes of optimization, the most important thing you need to know about this is that *it only runs once*.  Not only that, but it's doing an extremely simple and fast operation that could be just as simple and fast if it was written in C.  There is no point in having this inline assembly except to make the program more complex, which is another reason I think there is something strange about this assignment.  It seems to be full of red herrings.

Let's look at the assembler line by line.

The first line is a shorthand way of zeroing out the `%eax` register.  If you `xor` something with itself, the result is always zero.  (I do not know why this needs to be here, since you are overwriting the contents of `%eax` in the next line.)

The second line loads `%eax` with variable 1, which is the first input (`num1`).

The third line adds variable 2 (`num2`) to `%eax`.

The fourth line copies the result, which is loaded in `%eax`, to your output variable (`sum`).

The remaining lines define the variables we just referred to, in order (0, 1, 2) and also tells the compiler that you just used the `%eax` register so it will have to clear it before using it next.

You could just as easily replace all of that assembler with simple addition in C and it would not be any slower.  The compiler is very smart.

Basically, the only case you should need to use inline assembler is inside a loop that represents the bulk of the processing time for your program, in code that you know the compiler is optimizing poorly.  This inline assembler does not qualify on either count.  Especially since it does literally the exact same thing as the C line directly above it!  You could delete the asm() call entirely and not change the output of your program at all.

If you are tasked with making your program noticeably faster but restricted to editing only that inline assembler, you are on a fool's errand.

Comment: @AndfrewG Could you explain what the snippet of inline assembly does? To me it looks like a call to a function, but I don't understand the parameters. That will be a starting point for me and then I can make my way from there

Comment: Okay, I'll edit my answer so I can use proper formatting.

Comment: Thank you, that helps a bit. Last thing, what do the `%` do? This is for learning, so while the program may seem a waste of time, it's main purpose is to deal with inline assembly and see what it is like.

Comment: A single % specifies an operand, and a %% specifies a register.  See http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html for more info on inline assembler for GCC.

Comment: You've been quite helpful, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the best optimization for your program is to simply **remove** all of the inline assembly, as it does the same thing as the statement `sum = num1 + num2;` just above - and as a bonus, your program will become more portable, too!

Comment: I would gladly rather do it in C. However, I'm supposed to only change the assembly (to my knowledge) to improve it.

Comment: Because of how little sense the program makes as it stands, I am inclined to think there is some kind of mistake or misunderstanding about the objective of the assignment.

Comment: @AndrewG. You are correct, I edited the post. Sorry about that guys. (I was a little caught up in trying to figure out what each line was doing as I don't play with C often)